# Pharo How to list the arguments/parameters of a method?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Yes it's syntax fits on a postcard. But the details of all the existing classes are not easy to decipher for a newbie. I feel like seeing the arguments a method is intended to pass would be a big help in sorting it all out. Is there an easy way to do this. For example if I inspect and object blahBlah and, It is easy to find its methods foo:Bar: if I knew an easy way to see what should go after foo: and bar: then I could better understand what it is doing. I don't see a lot of readable comments for each method. Am I clicking the wrong places?

Comment: Just in case. Are you using the System Browser (or any other class browser)? Every method includes its full signature and source code. I'm asking because you say you are missing an "easy way to see what goes after `foo:` and `bar:`".

Comment: Thanks Leandro I think that will be the best place to look.

Answer (score 2):

An often used Smalltalk idiom suggests to use “Type Suggesting Parameter Names”<sup>1</sup>:

> Name parameters according to their most general expected class, preceded by “a” or “an”. If there is more than one parameter with the same expected class, precede the class with a descriptive word.

In Pharo you look up parameters and method comments in the **System Browser**.

`Collection>>at:put:` starts with:

```
at: anInteger put: anObject
    "Put anObject at element index anInteger. […]"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Kent Beck, *Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns*

Comment: It would of course be nice, if an editor would hint at these parameter names :) As far es I know, Pharo does not offer this at the moment.

Comment: You can see the parameters in the method signature and everywhere where the parameter is used in the method. Where would you like to see additional hints? In the sender of the message this is not possible because the invoked method is not determined before the message is actually sent. There could be another method with the same selector that names the arguments differently.

Comment: @JayK many dynamic languages had usable autocompletion for a long time now, there just wasn't enough engineering effort put into it in Pharo.